# Multithreaded .NET RabbitMQ publisher

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, rabbitmq

We have the following scenario using the .NET RabbitMQ library:

A worker thread picks up 'request' messages from a queue and dispatches them on multiple worker threads for processing. When complete, each worker thread then sends another message.

My question is what 'pattern' do people recommend for the sender in order to get the best throughput and stability?. For example:

1) A singleton 'publisher' instance that is accessed by all worker threads with a single Connection and IModel (using a 'lock' to synchronize access to the IModel)

2) A singleton 'publisher' instance that is accessed by all worker threads with a single Connection and which creates a new IModel for each send request.

or something else?

Comment: Sounds like a good problem for some trial and measurement.  I suspect that there are too many variables here for anyone to be able to give you an answer that is best for your particular use case.

Comment: It is probably better have each worker thread pickup messages from the message queue instead of having a central process distribute the work to the worker threads. It is possible to accomplish what you are suggesting using a shared memory queue (there is a thread safe implementation in the RabbitMQ lib) where the main process can put work items and the worker threads pick them up.

Comment: Thx both.Chris: will do that, was really hoping for some other people's real world experiences.

Comment: Apologies - hit 'send' prematurely. Chris: will do that but was hoping for some other people's real world experiences of similar scenarios (it feels like it should be a common usage pattern). Yavor: we actually already have the solution you suggest (single consumer thread; shared memory queue; worker threads 'ack' messages on completion of processing). What I'm really interested in is the pattern for the sender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to RabbitMQ user guide "IModel instances should not be used by more than one thread simultaneously: application code should maintain a clear notion of thread ownership for IModel instances"
In case a IModel is shared a lock should be use as you said but in my opinion this leads to a more complex code because connection and model should be keep alive in case of disconnection.

Although you don't mention if transactions are required in order to achieve more reliability on message delivery the channel must be set on transaction mode and maybe you will need a transaction per delivery.

Using a new model per delivery ensures a more simple error management but it
obviously will slow down the throughput (and the same by using transactions).

You could also, depending on your requirements,  use non durable queues and direct or fanout exchanges which provide better throughput.

As an example, on a development machine a windows service that consumes messages from a queue using one single thread (deserializing, making some business logic, and finally send a new serialized message using transactions by opening/closing connection and model can achieve about 3000 messages processed per second.
(serialization was done via XmlSerializer which is worst than DataContractSerializer)

Comment: Thanks - going to mark this an the accepted answer as there are some useful pointers in here. For the record, we are now looking at building an 'async' sender that uses a shared queue and internal thread to do the actual sending.